# Get value from dynamic radiofield in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a quiz app and I got stuck on getting the answer from the form where i have a RadioButton.

Relevant code:
This is my html form:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
   <form method="POST" action="">
        <div class="btn-group-lg" data-toggle="buttons">
             <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" required> {{answer.answer}}
             </label>
        </div>
   </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Here I have the .py code where i make a form for my RadioButton, where I make my root and i have my functions:

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    radio_button = RadioField('option', choices=[])

question_list = []
answer_list = []

@app.route('/question/<int:index>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def question(index):
    questions = getQuestions()
    for question in questions:
        question_list.append(question['question_id'])
    answers = getQuestionAnswers(question_list[index])
    questions_lenght = len(questions)
    form = QuestionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        option = form.radio_button.data
        print(option)
        return render_template('question.html', question=questions[index]["question"], answers=answers, index=index, questions_lenght=questions_lenght, form=form)

    return render_template('question.html', question=questions[index]["question"], answers=answers, index=index, questions_lenght=questions_lenght, form=form)

def getQuestions():
    mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  
                    user="",        
                    passwd="", 
                    db="",
                    cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)    
    cur = mysql.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM questions")
    questions = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return questions

def getQuestionAnswers( question_id ):
    mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",  
                    user="",        
                    passwd="", 
                    db="",
                    cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)    
    cur = mysql.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = %s", [question_id])
    answers = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return answers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key=''
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My problem is in the following code block:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        option = form.radio_button.data
        print(option)
```

Nothing gets printed.

Comment: Is your code indentation correct?

Comment: In your HTML I would have expected to see something like this example from the WTForms docs:
`{% for subfield in form.radio %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
        <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: you are probably right, but i don't know how to display the answers then